# Multiple classes using the same method

Tags: java, oop

I have two methods that have the same functionality. The only difference is that they are initialising two differnet classes where both classes have an iner class with the same name `ClassC`. I do not have access to modify the way the classes are implemented but I want to simply these two methods into one method

```
   public static void  methodA(String A,String B){    
        ClassA.ClassC cc = new ClassA.ClassC (); //initialising inner class
        cc.addSub(A,B);

        ClassA aa= new ClassA ();
        aa.setSub(cc); 
    }


    public static void methodB(String A,String B) {
        ClassB.ClassC cc = new ClassB.ClassC();
        cc.addSub(A,B);

        ClassB bb = new ClassB();
        bb.setSub(cc);
    }
```

Comment: If you ask me, that's an ugly design :) But is it possible that you can add an example of what you want to achieve. It is not clear to me.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to do this.

Comment: Those two methods are very different.  One works with ClassA and one with ClassB.  The only similarity is that both have methods called `setSub()`, but these methods could do completely different things.

Comment: I don't think this can be simplified unless ClassA and ClassB extend the same base class or interface.

Comment: You can pass these classes instances as parameters to your desired single method :)

Comment: @semenchikus can you please provide an example on how you would go about this?

Comment: `public static void singleMethod(String A,String B, Object classC, Object classAorB) {
    classC.addSub(A,B);
    classAorB.setSub(classC);
}
`

Comment: Just in case I want clear I want to have one general method as shown below where GeneralClass can either be ClassA or ClassB

public static void methodgen(String A,String B) {
        GeneralClass.ClassC cc = new GeneralClass.ClassC();
        cc.addSub(A,B);

        GeneralClass bb = new GeneralClass();
        bb.setSub(cc);
    }

Comment: See above, you can use smth like this (of course, you need to cast objects).

Comment: You can't create such GeneralClass. The only way how to do similar things is to change source code of the classes and then use polymorphism.

Comment: Thanks for the information :)

Comment: You are welcome ;)

Comment: You mention "inner classes" but you show syntax for non-inner (i.e., static) nested classes.